# Passing and ArrayList<Service> through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have a class called Service, which is used to create Service objects using this constructor

```
public Service(int id, String service_name, String service_code) {
    this.id = id;
    this.service_name = service_name;
    this.service_code = service_code;
}
```

then I create a list call service list as with the following signature

```
List<Service> serviceList = new ArrayList<Service>
```

I have try to pass this ArrayList through `Intent` Object like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Classname.this, anotherClass.class);
i.putExtras("serviceList",serviceList);
startActivity(i);
```

But it fails. What is the way I pass through intent with ArrayList object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom class has to implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable` in order to serialize/de-serialize within an Intent.

Your class `Service` has to look like this for example (used a generator http://www.parcelabler.com/)

```
public class Service implements Parcelable {
private int id;
private String service_name;
private String service_code;
public Service(int id, String service_name, String service_code) {
this.id = id;
this.service_name = service_name;
this.service_code = service_code;
}


protected Service(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    service_name = in.readString();
    service_code = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(service_name);
    dest.writeString(service_code);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Service> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Service>() {
    @Override
    public Service createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Service(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Service[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Service[size];
    }
};
```

}

Then you can use `getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra()` with casting

```
ArrayList<Service> serviceList= intent.<Service>getParcelableArrayList("list"));
```

For sending you use it like this

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", yourServiceArrayList);
```

Note that the `yourServiceArrayList` should be an ArrayList

if it is List the you can pass through

`intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) yourServiceArrayList);`

Comment: How do i send the parcalable intent

Comment: @nifCody Basically like this `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", yourServiceArrayList)`

Comment: do we need to cast the yourServiceArrayList

Comment: intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("serviceCard", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) serviceCart);

Comment: @nifCody No you don't. Did you change your `Service` class like I provided?

Comment: @nifCody Allright. Does it not work? Because it should work.

Comment: The above one is my Service Class which look like after created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129997/discussion-between-murat-k-and-nifcody).

Answer (score 1):

You can use parcelable interface for *'Service'* class, and send object through

intent using *'putParcelableArrayListExtra'* method and to retrive data you can use

*'getParcelableArrayListExtra'*.

For your reference 
[refer this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/android-sending-object-from-one-activity-to-another-using-parcelable)  link

Answer (score 1):

Implement object class with Serializable .
eg.

```
class abc implements Serializable{
//your code
}
```

then try this code

```
ArrayList<abc> fileList = new ArrayList<abc>();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
 intent.putSerializable("arraylisty",filelist);
startActivity(intent);
```

and on other side receive intent like

```
your arraylist objact=intent.getSerializableExtra(String name)
```